# How to convert a singleton in c# to c++?

Tags: c++, singleton

I have this c# code:

```
class Animacion
{

    private static Animacion instancia;
    public static Animacion Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instancia == null)
            {
                instancia = new Animacion();
            }
            return instancia;
        }
    }
```

I want to convert that code to c++, I tryed to use a code converter from tangible software solutions and I got this:

```
//.h file code:

class Animacion
{

    private:
        static Animacion *instancia;
    public:
        static Animacion *getInstance() const;
};

//.cpp file code:

Animacion *Animacion::getInstance() const
{
    if (instancia == nullptr)
    {
        instancia = new Animacion();
    }
    return instancia;
}
```

When I use the code generated from the converter I get errors like:

```
error: C2272: 'getInstance' : modifiers not allowed on static member functions
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static Animacion *getInstance() const;` get rid of the const. There's no point making a `static` class member function `const` in c++, hence the compiler error.

---

Also the established idiom for singletons in c++ looks rather like:

```
class Animacion {

private:
    Animacion() {}
    Animacion(const Animacion&) = delete;
    Animacion& operator=(const Animacion&) = delete;
public:
    static Animacion& getInstance() {
        static Animacion theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }
};
```

---

Further you should note, that **Singleton** is a really questionable design pattern, and you likely could live without it, in preference of an injected interface for the clients. That would help in decoupling implementation, from usage.